# How to make mysqld stop running, when Foreman (Procfile) stops running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreman, mysql, procfile

I have a simple Procfile for a Rails app:

```
web: rails server -p $PORT
worker: bundle exec rake jobs:work
mysql: /usr/local/bin/mysqld --log-error=/dev/stout
```

All of the processes start up correctly which is great. However when I stop Foreman with CTRL-C, mysqld does not stop. It keeps running in the background.

How do I make mysqld stop when Foreman stops?

Is there another way of starting mysql via command line which would work, that I don't know about?

Answer (score 4):

After some more Googling, I found the answer here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53062/2566

```
mysql: /usr/local/bin/mysqld --gdb
```

Answer (score 0):

On my computer, it takes about 6 seconds to stop MySQL, but foreman automatically sends a `SIGKILL` after 5, so when running `foreman`, you need to extend the time before the `SIGKILL`. I used 10 seconds, YMMV.

```
foreman start -t 10
```

**mysql.sh**

```
trap 'brew services stop mysql' INT TERM

ps aux | grep -v grep | grep -i mysqld

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "MySQL is already running"
else
  echo "Starting MySQL"
  brew services start mysql
fi

# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42911
sleep 2147483647
```

**Procfile**

```
mysql: ./mysql.sh
```